# Including custom library in Python job in Jenkins

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, jenkins, python-requests

I have a Python script that checks statuses of list of urls defined inside it.

I'm importing and using `requests` library inside the script. I need to run this script on Jenkins instance which have Python 2.7 installed.

The thing is it doesn't contain requests library installed in Jenkins instance. I don't have access to manually install requests library using `pip` in the `Jenkins` instance.

What I need if there is a way is to download the requests library dynamically using shell commands or something and use that wheel file (which is located in some downloaded folder and point to that directory) to act as library for the scrip I'm about to run.

Comment: You should read up on Python virtualenv

Comment: Yeah. But even for installing virtualenv, I need access to the machine manually which I don't have. and If I do install it using script, I need to install it everytime I run the job. That's the issue here.